# Regex for the MAC ID pattern to restrict FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF and leading 01-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx,

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried to construct a working regex for the mentioned scenario but it's not working.

1. It should restrict the MAC IDs with leading "01" (01-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx). eg

`01:AA:BB:05:31:01` <- Not valid.

`21:51:51:31:01:AA` <- Valid.

2. It should restrict `FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF` full match.

What I have done so far is here.

```
^((?!01|FF|88|87|ff|00)[0-9a-fA-F]{2}([:-]|$)){6}$
```

Comment: Is there a reason you've chosen RegEx to solve the problem? Why not split by colon and process octets separately?

Comment: I have already a working regex to validate the MAC IDs but I need to restrict the  "FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF" full match and leading 01. I though RegEx would reduce the line of code.

Comment: That's exactly the case when less lines doesn't mean 'easier to read and maintain/scale'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to escape anything that begins with `01|FF|88|87|ff|00` use this

```
pattern=/^(?=[^01|FF|88|87|ff|00])([0-9a-fA-F]{2}[:]){5}[0-9a-fA-F]{2}/gm
```

if you want to escape beginning `01|88|87|00` and only a full patter FF use this one instead

```
pattern=/^(?!01|88|87|00|FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF)([0-9a-fA-F]{2}[:]){5}[0-9a-fA-F]{2}/
```

Comment: can you give me a scenario where it failed?

Comment: plz visit this link. https://regex101.com/r/911Ulc/3

Comment: I have visited the link it's matching the last one only because it doesn't begin with 01ff.. isn't that what you want ?

Comment: I asked help for FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF full match restrict not starting with FF.

Comment: I have updated my answer check it out now and let me know if it needs anymore improvements

Comment: hers is the link with the new pattern https://regex101.com/r/ZH9ec9/1

Comment: I have added a new pattern that will escape FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF full match

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217754/discussion-between-abhishek-gautam-and-sven-hig).

Comment: I have added the pattern in  my answer to match FF:FF:BA:15:2B:1E and exclude FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF check it out

Comment: I have checked with few more test mac IDs , like : 11:FF:BA:15:2B:1E
03:ff:ff:ff:ff:f0 , these should matched but not happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
var macAddressAllowed = function(macAddr) {
  // regEX for valid MAC address
  var regExp = "^([0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]:){5}([0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F])$";
  var regex = new RegExp(regExp);
  var validMac = regex.test(macAddr);
  if(!validMac){
    return false;
  }else{
    macAddr = macAddr ? macAddr.toLowerCase() : '';
    var macAllowed = (macAddr === 'ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff' || macAddr.split(':')[0] === '01');
    return macAllowed ? false: true;
  }
 };
```